# How to anchor 2 datagrids to each other?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to put 2 `datagrid`s side by side. I can't seem to anchor them to each other because when I try to anchor them, the arrow goes straight to the opposite side, thus, the `datagrid`s overlaps each other when I maximize the window

Answer (score 0):

Try to contain both of them inside StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal":

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <DataGrid></DataGrid>
    <DataGrid></DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

in order to set datagrids to "fill" parent controls you need to read this question - [How to get controls in WPF to fill available space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108/how-to-get-controls-in-wpf-to-fill-available-space)

Comment: When I do that, the grids won't strech at all.

Comment: You have to set datagrids to "fill" parent controls.

Comment: Ahh sorry, this is not available in WPF :(